# How to remove parameter from URL after 301 redirect using Mod Rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to fix a few rewrites. The 301 redirect is working, but it adds a new parameter to the URL.

The current output after the redirect strikes is: 
http://exampelpage.com/new-page?pageID=oldpage

We want to have this output instead:
http://exampelpage.com/new-page

Current .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampelpage\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://exampelpage.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#blog
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ /index.php?currentpage=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)/([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)/([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]

#admin
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&subpage=admin/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://exampelpage.com/404


# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /oldpage?__hstc=113653464.efdd41a653140fecad23cdf89637a97c.1426377600080.1426377600081.1426377600082.1&__hssc=113653464.1.1426377600083&__hsfp=59720947 http://exampelpage.com/new-page
Redirect 301 /oldpage http://exampelpage.com/new-page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteRule for it.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)oldpage?__hstc=(.*)$ /oldpage [R=301,L]
```

RewriteRule only works with string.

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt really do anything. I get that this aint easy to explain, but our system add's the pageID at the end of the URL. We simply want to remove that part, this only happen after the redirect is done.